# Linear programming: reduce a constraint that includes a minimum

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have an *almost* linear programme. However one of the constraints has a form $z = min(x,y)$ (all the other things are linear in the model). Is there a way to substitute this with something (or introduce additional variables) to turn this into a linear programme?

In other words, I have the problem that looks like the following:
$$
\mathbf c' \mathbf x \to \min,
$$
s.t.
$$
A \mathbf x = \mathbf b,\quad x_1 = \min(x_2, x_3).
$$

**Update:** I thought about substituting the constraint with a pair of constraints $x_1 \le x_2$, $x_1 \le x_3$ but it doesn't work if the coefficient of $x_1$ is positive in $\mathbf c$. And this is the case in my problem (actually all the entries of $\mathbf c$ a positive/nonnegative).

Comment: Is the coefficient of $x_{1}$ in $c$ positive or negative?  Are you willing to consider using a 0-1 integer variable if necessary?

Comment: all the entries in $\mathbf c$ are positive/nonnegative. I would prefer to avoid 0-1 integer but if it's the only way to go...

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3491088/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/118981/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model this with a single binary variable and additional constraints, or you can just solve two linear programs, one with $x_1=x_2\le x_3$ and one with $x_1=x_3\le x_2$, and take whichever solution yields the better objective value.

Comment: I wonder which method is faster...

Comment: [Here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/how-to-linearize-min-function-as-a-constraint) is a binary formulation, which requires an upper bound of $M$ on your variables $x_2$ and $x_3$.  It would probably be faster than solving two independent LPs from scratch.  But you could speed up the two-LP approach by first solving your original LP with $x_1\le x_2$ and $x_1\le x_3$ and then using the dual simplex method to solve the two LPs starting from an optimal basis.  This approach mimics what a MILP solver would do under the hood, but without requiring the big-M constraints.

Comment: actually, in my problem, all $x_i <= 1$ (this is enforced by $A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ constraints). Hence, $M = 1$ naturally.